# When Newman run postman colleciton how to exclude certain rest url pattern

Tags: rest, postman-newman

I have a windows bath file to run newman with the given postman request collection with html report.

```
newman run my_collectoin.postman_collection.json -r htmlextra
```

in this collection I have few REST endpoints as
/expriment/trigger
/expriment/test

How to tell newman run not to run any endpoint which has /expriment/* pattern?